# Amicable pairs of numbers and their product

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $(a,b)$ ($a<b$) is an amicable pair and $(c,d)$ ($c<d$) another pair such that $$ab=cd$$

> Is it possible that (c,d) is an amicable pair as well ? Or is it easy to show that it is impossible ?

In other words : Can distinct amicable pairs have the same product ?

Comment: I dont think that it should say c/d it should say c,d

Comment: Upto $10^8$, the pairs give distinct products.

Comment: @Peter any tips on how to prove it?

Comment: I just used brute force, so no.