# Do positive integers $a,b,c,d$ exist with the given properties?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Inspired by this question : [Amicable pairs of numbers and their product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855993/amicable-pairs-of-numbers-and-their-product#comment5897566_2855993)

I ask whether positive integers $a,b,c,d$ exist with the following properties :

$(1)\ \ \ \ \ 0<a<b<c<d\ \ \ $

$(2)\ \ \ \ \ ad=bc$

$(3)\ \ \ \ \ \sigma(a)=\sigma(d)$

$(4)\ \ \ \ \ \sigma(b)=\sigma(c)$

where $\sigma(n)$ denotes the divisor-sum-function. Upto $d=200$, there is no solution, so I conjecture that not all the conditions can be satisfied.

This would answer the question , whether distinct pairs of amicable numbers can have the same product , in a negative way.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you should start by thinking about the prime factorizations of $ad$ and $bc$ and the formula for $\sigma.$

Comment: Usually, I do not care of downvotes, but in this case I am really curious for the reason ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a=210$, $b=310$, $c=357$, $d=527$.

Comment: OK, so this cannot be used for the proof.